# Delphi 7 TListSortCompare that can access object properties

Tags: delphi, custom-controls, delphi-7, tlist

I'm writing a custom component that owns a Tlist of records . the problem is : how the TListSortCompare function -used to sort the list's records- can access  component's fields ?
the compiler refuses object method as a list compareator , and in the component's unit there is no instance created yet to access .

Thanks
Wael

Comment: Can you give a coding example of your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compare function can't be a non-static class method, it has to be either a standalone function or a static class method, which means it has no `Self` parameter to *directly* access any component object, it only knows about the 2 input parameters that point to the records being compared.

So, the only ways for you to *indirectly* access the component object inside your compare function is if you either:

- store a pointer to the component object in a global or `threadvar` variable.
- store a pointer to the component object inside the records themselves.
- use a thunk for the comparer, where the pointer to the component object is stored hidden inside the thunk itself (this is the technique the VCL uses internally to allow Win32 HWND message handlers to call `TWinControl.WindowProc` on a per-object basis).

Comment: Remy,  yes a static var , either a pointer to the object or just the fields I need , is what came to my mind . But I think this value will affect all created instances of the component that coexist in the session , doesn't it ?

Comment: @DrWael if you use a global, yes. And if you use all of those instances in a single thread, then that may be good enough. But if you need multi-threaded support then a global is not an option.